# Can we write BSON files in R without MongoDB

Tags: r, bson

I am trying to explore alternate serialization/un-serialization in R.

Is it possible to read /write data in `BSON` file format in R without actually creating or using a `MongoDB` database?

I browsed the `rmongodb` package description, and it appeared that the package might require one to use a `MongoDB` database for reading/writing `BSON` files.

Comment: bson is actually a fairly simple format, you could write your own, but other than that if there's not a package for it MongoDB could be your only choice. Also, check out msgpack, very similar, binary json like data serialization